# How can I hold object between invocations in JNI?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have an Android app with native code. How can I hold the reference to an object between invocations of native methods?

```
// 1: create native object and hold it
Object obj = jni_wrapper.native_getObject();

// ... do smth

// 2: return an object back to native code
Object result = jni_wrapper.native_doSmthWithObject(obj);
```

So the code is expected to hold a reference to an object and find it somehow (between 1: and 2: in the example above). I can create my own class and special instance fields (if necessary) to hold references.

I've used the next solution (just holding pointer to instance in "pointer" instance field of Index object) but it seems to be not working.

Java (Index.java):

```
/**
 *  CXIndex
 */
public class Index {

    private long pointer;

    public long getPointer() {
        return pointer;
    }
}
```

Native code:

```
// index
static jclass IndexClass;
static jmethodID IndexConstructor;
static jfieldID IndexPointerField;

void bindIndex(JNIEnv *env)
{
    IndexClass = env->FindClass("name/antonsmirnov/xxx/dto/Index");
    IndexConstructor = env->GetMethodID(IndexClass, "<init>", "()V");
    IndexPointerField = env->GetFieldID(IndexClass, "pointer", "J");
}

// map CXIndex
jobject mapIndex(JNIEnv *env, CXIndex *index)
{
    if (IndexClass == NULL)
        bindIndex(env);


    jobject obj = env->NewObject(IndexClass, IndexConstructor);
    jlong jpointer = reinterpret_cast<jlong>(index);

    env->SetLongField(obj, IndexPointerField, jpointer);
    return obj;
}

// map Index -> CXIndex
CXIndex unmapIndex(JNIEnv *env, jobject jindex)
{
    if (IndexClass == NULL)
        bindIndex(env);

    jlong jpointer = env->GetLongField(jindex, IndexPointerField);
    CXIndex *ptr = reinterpret_cast<CXIndex*>(jpointer);
    return *ptr;
}
```

This relates to Android which can bring specific behaviour!

Comment: PS. Also i'm not sure that holding static references is good idea according to http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Comment: [tag:compiler-construction] has exactly nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function

```
jlong JNI_mypackage_myclass_createMyNativePeer() {

      return new MyNativePeer();
}
```

Then in Java you keep the returned value in your class.

```
class MyWrapper {
    private long mPeer;

    public void createPeer() {
       mPeer = createMyNativePeer();
    }

   private native long createMyNativePeer();

   public void controlPeer(int param) {
            controlPeer(mPeer, param);
   }

   private native void controlPeer(long peer, int param);

}
```

Then you pass that value to your controlling functions:

```
jvoid JNI_mypackage_myclass_controlPeer(jlong peer, int someParam) {
      ((*MyNativePeer)peer)->doSomething(param);
}
```

Comment: just holding var pointer seems to be not working as memory is freed after invocation returned result or smth.. the app crashes while trying to use passed from java pointer.

Comment: I've looked using env->NewGlobalRef but it relates to jobject instances only and i need to hold my class

Comment: i've checked this and it's not working. native method 2 can't work with "unboxed" pointer from java

Comment: but "boxing" and "unboxing" is correct - i can use it within the same invocation of native method, so probably in the 2nd invocation of native method it's another env reference or memory is freed between native methods invocations

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two problems here.

1. You can't hold a static reference to a `jobject` or a `jclass`. You need a `GlobalRef` or `WeakGlobalRef` to do that.
2. There is a complete absence of error-checking in your JNI code. The results of `GetClass()`, `GetMethodID()`, `GetFieldID()`, `GetLongField()`, etc., must all be checked and pending exceptions also checked for.

However I don't see why you need this. Your first solution is much easier, and can be implemented invisibly by wrapping private native methods in public Java methods that call them and provide the required object automatically, where the object can be stored in the class that has the native methods.